# Can you be in the “95% percentile”?

Tags: statistics

I have a feeling there's only one way to say this: you can be in the “95th percentile”. A colleague of mine says it's OK to say “the 95% percentile”, which doesn't seem to make mathematical sense to me.

What's correct?

Comment: Stick to your intuition: **you're correct** and your colleague is wrong. Their version is not only tautological, it sounds ridiculous when spoken: *the ninety-five per cent percentile*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Percentiles, whether we mean rank or range, are discussed using ordinal numbers: first, 50th, 95th, etc. To say "ninety-five percent percentile" would be considered an error in any kind of formal or academic setting, as well as being redundant.

> Percentile ranks are reported on an ordinal scale.

[Applied Statistics in Education and Psychology I](https://www.andrews.edu/~thayerj/EDRM611/Summer2001ObjectivesUnit3.htm)

Comment: Not to mention that percent literally means "out of a hundred," so 95 out of 100 out of a further hundred is a statement best left to actuaries.

Comment: I think even an actuary would struggle. They could deal with the 95 out of a hundred out of a hundred. But this is not just 95 out of a hundred but the ordinal of 95 out of a hundred, so it means the 0.95th percentile. Only a philosopher of mathematics would think about that and then only if they were having trouble sleeping.